# How to match and replace list elements in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list in Python with certain elements.  I want to replace these elements with their corresponding elements from another list.

I want to have another list that relates elements in a list like:

```
x = ['red','orange','yellow','green','blue','purple','pink']
y = ['cherry','orange','banana','apple','blueberry','eggplant','grapefruit']
```

so that a new list will be created with the the corresponding elements from y whose elements are in x. So

```
r = ['green','red','purple']
```

will become

```
r = ['apple','cherry','eggplant']
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what did you tried ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a mapping from one list to another:

```
my_mapping = dict(zip(x, y))
```

The `zip` part is mainly a formality: `dict` expects the argument to be a sequence of pairs, rather than a pair of sequences.

Then apply this mapping to every member of `r` using a list comprehension:

```
new_r = [my_mapping[elem] for elem in r]
```

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries are the best option for this. They are maps of key-value pairs so that if I index a dictionary with a key, it will return the value under that key.

Let's make a new dictionary using the `zip` function that takes two lists:

```
mapper = dict(zip(x,y))
```

Now, if we want to change a list r to its counterpart with elements from the new list:

```
r = [mapper[i] for i in r]
```

This takes each element in r and uses the dictionary to turn it into its counterpart.